# Where is the definition of "TypeIdentifier"

Tags: delphi, rtti, typeinfo

I would need to write a function that performs operations in RTTI mode on data, of which I do not know a priori the type.
I tried to write a function like this:
`function doSomething (T: TypeIdentifier): Boolean;`
as when using the expression `TypeInfo(T)` he expects as a type parameter `TypeIdentifier` [image: see the snapshot]

But when I try to compile I get an error because the type TypeIdentifier not recognized.
Someone could explain me how I can do to send a data type of which I know the type only at runtime?
Thanks to the availability.
Enzo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TypeInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypeInfo) is an [intrinsic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines) function that uses compiler magic. That is the compiler generates the code that implements the function rather than it being part of the runtime library.

You don't have access to such magic. You cannot create a function that accepts a type identifier in the manner of `TypeInfo`.  So you need to make your function accept what `TypeInfo` returns, a pointer to the type info, `PTypeInfo`.

You'd call your function like this:

```
DoSomething(TypeInfo(SomeTypeIdentifier));
```

Now technically, you may notice that `TypeInfo` returns a value of type `Pointer`. That's because `PTypeInfo` is defined in another unit, `TypInfo` and the `System` unit where all intrinsics are defined is not allowed to use `TypInfo`. But as stated in the documentation linked above, `TypeInfo` returns a pointer to `TTypeInfo`.

Comment: Thanks, David.I'll apply your suggestion ... :-)